# VBA for add data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to re-create a marco based excel and would like to understand the below code. I understand that this code is going to add data to the worksheet "TableData". I also understand that this code is going to add data from the worksheet "CompBreakdown Workpaper" cells T750, Y750 and Z750 to the "TableData" sheet (in the first, second and third cells). However, I am not able to understand ListObject and ListRow and its relevance.

```
Sub AddData()
Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow

Set the_sheet = Sheets("TableData")
Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = Sheets("CompBreakdown 
Workpaper").Range("T750")
table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = Sheets("CompBreakdown 
Workpaper").Range("Y750")
table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = Sheets("CompBreakdown 
Workpaper").Range("Z750")

End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839458.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: `ListObject`s in vba are what the Excel interface calls "Table"

Answer (score 0):

@Santhosh,`table_list_object` object allows VBA to basically store and manipualte lists.

`table_object_row` is the row characterstics of the `table_list_object`. so you specify with rows/range you want included.